# Zoom Canvas to Mouse Cursor

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, zooming, scrollwheel

I'm programming a HTML5 < canvas > project that involves zooming in and out of images using the scroll wheel.
I want to zoom towards the cursor like google maps does but I'm completely lost on how to calculate the movements.

What I have: image x and y (top-left corner); image width and height; cursor x and y relative to the center of the canvas.

Comment: you should accept this answer or revise your question

Answer (score 280):

In short, you want to `translate()` the canvas context by your offset, `scale()` it to zoom in or out, and then `translate()` back by the opposite of the mouse offset. Note that you need to transform the cursor position from screen space into the transformed canvas context.

```js
ctx.translate(pt.x,pt.y);
ctx.scale(factor,factor);
ctx.translate(-pt.x,-pt.y);
```

### Demo: http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_zoom_to_cursor.html

I've put up a [full working example](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_zoom_to_cursor.html) on my website for you to examine, supporting dragging, click to zoom in, shift-click to out, or scroll wheel up/down.

*The only (current) issue is that [Safari zooms too fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527601/normalizing-mousewheel-speed-across-browsers) compared to Chrome or Firefox.*

Comment: Hey @Phrogz this is awesome! I just wonder if we can limit the dragging so that one cant drag the image out of the boundaries. If there is no more image left to drag, the dragging should just stop there instead of allowing to drag indefinetly. I took my stab on it but it seems I can't get the math right :-(

Comment: Hi Phrogz - the code is brilliant and works great but I have found a situation where it falls down.  If you have a dynamically sized canvas then the next time you attempt to move or scale anything it doesnt work correctly.  What would you have to do to fix it under this situation? Thanks

Comment: Did someone found a solution to the dynamically sized canvas problem from @Chris. Also is there the possibility to limit the zoom factor so a and d are between 1 and 5, so i can restrict the zooming level? Thanks

Comment: @Christoph it is easy. get the scale - you can take scale from :
var scale = ctx.getTransform().a;
then take the current top left position of image:
var curX = ctx.getTransform().e;
var curY = ctx.getTransform().f;
estimate the change in position:
var deltaX = pt.x - dragStart.x;
var deltaY = pt.y - dragStart.y;
then there is original image size, lets take width for example (when scale=1): imageW
and there is canvas width: canvasW
then the condition should be false to allow drag:
curX + deltaX + imageW * scale < canvasW
and one more
(curX + deltaX > 0 || curY + deltaY > 0)

Comment: @iam_peter I did it using following code in zoom function, in place of ctx.scale function call:
var scale = ctx.getTransform().a;
var decision = true;
if (factor < 1) {
   // this is zoom out
   if (scale < scaleLowerLimit) {
 decision = false;
   }
} else if (factor > 1) {
   // this is zoom in
   if (scale > scaleUpperLimit) {
 decision = false;
   }
} else {
   decision = false;
}
   
if (decision == true) {
   ctx.scale(factor, factor);
}

set the scaleLowerLimit to 1 and scaleUpperLimit to 5. hope it helps

Comment: @phrogz can we do the zoom to already generated canvas with text and images ?

Comment: Would this be hard to implement on mobile with gestures?
Like, allow 2 finger pinch to zoom in on only the image but not the entire website?

Comment: The single click to zoom in feature and Shift-Click to zoom out do not work in Chrome, but the work fine in IE and FireFox. Any ideas?

Comment: @MattSlay works fine for me in Chrome 43 on Windows. Email me via the link at the bottom of the test page to discuss further.

Comment: Weird! I'm certain it wasn't working. Restarted Chrome, and it's working fine now. Thanks.

Comment: How to reset this zoom?

Comment: @explorer `ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);`

Comment: @Phrogz is there any easy way to snap the contents of the canvas to the canvas when zooming?

Comment: @Phrogz is there an easy way to save the position of zoom/drag? I can't seem to get it to work. I have a function for redrawing images which clears the canvas. I want it redraw images and focus on the same point as before (for image comparison).

Comment: @Phrogz, I did that but it always shifts to the right once i set it again. As a workaround, I'm now just clearing the canvas and redrawing images.

Answer (score 15):

I hope, these JS libraries will help you:
(HTML5, JS)

1. Loupe

http://www.netzgesta.de/loupe/

2. CanvasZoom

https://github.com/akademy/CanvasZoom

3. Scroller

https://github.com/zynga/scroller

As for me, I'm using loupe. It's awesome!
For you the best case - scroller.

Answer (score 13):

I recently needed to archive same results as Phrogz had already done but instead of using `context.scale()`, I calculated each object size based on ratio.

This is what I came up with. Logic behind it is very simple. Before scaling, I calculate point distance from edge in percentages and later adjust viewport to correct place.

It took me quite a while to come up with it, hope it saves someones time.

```js
$(function () {
  var canvas = $('canvas.main').get(0)
  var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d')

  var ratio = 1
  var vpx = 0
  var vpy = 0
  var vpw = window.innerWidth
  var vph = window.innerHeight

  var orig_width = 4000
  var orig_height = 4000

  var width = 4000
  var height = 4000

  $(window).on('resize', function () {
    $(canvas).prop({
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight,
    })
  }).trigger('resize')

  $(canvas).on('wheel', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault() // for stackoverflow

    var step

    if (ev.originalEvent.wheelDelta) {
      step = (ev.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) ? 0.05 : -0.05
    }

    if (ev.originalEvent.deltaY) {
      step = (ev.originalEvent.deltaY > 0) ? 0.05 : -0.05
    }

    if (!step) return false // yea..

    var new_ratio = ratio + step
    var min_ratio = Math.max(vpw / orig_width, vph / orig_height)
    var max_ratio = 3.0

    if (new_ratio < min_ratio) {
      new_ratio = min_ratio
    }

    if (new_ratio > max_ratio) {
      new_ratio = max_ratio
    }

    // zoom center point
    var targetX = ev.originalEvent.clientX || (vpw / 2)
    var targetY = ev.originalEvent.clientY || (vph / 2)

    // percentages from side
    var pX = ((vpx * -1) + targetX) * 100 / width
    var pY = ((vpy * -1) + targetY) * 100 / height

    // update ratio and dimentsions
    ratio = new_ratio
    width = orig_width * new_ratio
    height = orig_height * new_ratio

    // translate view back to center point
    var x = ((width * pX / 100) - targetX)
    var y = ((height * pY / 100) - targetY)

    // don't let viewport go over edges
    if (x < 0) {
      x = 0
    }

    if (x + vpw > width) {
      x = width - vpw
    }

    if (y < 0) {
      y = 0
    }

    if (y + vph > height) {
      y = height - vph
    }

    vpx = x * -1
    vpy = y * -1
  })

  var is_down, is_drag, last_drag

  $(canvas).on('mousedown', function (ev) {
    is_down = true
    is_drag = false
    last_drag = { x: ev.clientX, y: ev.clientY }
  })

  $(canvas).on('mousemove', function (ev) {
    is_drag = true

    if (is_down) {
      var x = vpx - (last_drag.x - ev.clientX)
      var y = vpy - (last_drag.y - ev.clientY)

      if (x <= 0 && vpw < x + width) {
        vpx = x
      }

      if (y <= 0 && vph < y + height) {
        vpy = y
      }

      last_drag = { x: ev.clientX, y: ev.clientY }
    }
  })

  $(canvas).on('mouseup', function (ev) {
    is_down = false
    last_drag = null

    var was_click = !is_drag
    is_drag = false

    if (was_click) {

    }
  })

  $(canvas).css({ position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0 }).appendTo(document.body)

  function animate () {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate)

    canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

    canvasContext.lineWidth = 1
    canvasContext.strokeStyle = '#ccc'

    var step = 100 * ratio

    for (var x = vpx; x < width + vpx; x += step) {
      canvasContext.beginPath()
      canvasContext.moveTo(x, vpy)
      canvasContext.lineTo(x, vpy + height)
      canvasContext.stroke()
    }
    for (var y = vpy; y < height + vpy; y += step) {
      canvasContext.beginPath()
      canvasContext.moveTo(vpx, y)
      canvasContext.lineTo(vpx + width, y)
      canvasContext.stroke()
    }

    canvasContext.strokeRect(vpx, vpy, width, height)

    canvasContext.beginPath()
    canvasContext.moveTo(vpx, vpy)
    canvasContext.lineTo(vpx + width, vpy + height)
    canvasContext.stroke()

    canvasContext.beginPath()
    canvasContext.moveTo(vpx + width, vpy)
    canvasContext.lineTo(vpx, vpy + height)
    canvasContext.stroke()

    canvasContext.restore()
  }

  animate()
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas class="main"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

I took @Phrogz's answer as a basis and made a small library that enables canvas with dragging, zooming and rotating.
Here is the example.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
//assuming that @param draw is a function where you do your main drawing.
var control = new CanvasManipulation(canvas, draw)
control.init()
control.layout()
//now you can drag, zoom and rotate in canvas
```

You can find more detailed examples and documentation on the project's [page](https://bitbucket.org/vogdb/canvas-manipulation)

Answer (score 6):

### Faster

Using `ctx.setTransform` gives you more performance than multiple matrix calls `ctx.translate`, `ctx.scale`, `ctx.translate`.

No need for complex transformation inversions as and expensive DOM matrix calls tp converts point between zoomed and screen coordinate systems.

### Flexible

Flexibility as you don't need to use `ctx.save` and `ctx.restore` if you are rendering content at using different transforms. Returning to the transform with `ctx.setTransform` rather than the potentially frame rate wreaking `ctx.restore`call

Easy to invert the transform and get the world coordinates of a (screen) pixel position and the other way round.

### Examples

Using mouse and mouse wheel to zoom in and out at mouse position

An example using this method to [scale page content at a point (mouse) via CSS transform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60235061/3877726) CSS Demo at bottom of answer also has a copy of the demo from the next example.

And an example of this method used to [scale canvas content at a point using setTransform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45528455/3877726)

### How

Given a scale and pixel position you can get the new scale as follow...

```
const origin = {x:0, y:0};         // canvas origin
var scale = 1;                     // current scale
function scaleAt(x, y, scaleBy) {  // at pixel coords x, y scale by scaleBy
    scale *= scaleBy;
    origin.x = x - (x - origin.x) * scaleBy;
    origin.y = y - (y - origin.y) * scaleBy;
}
```

To position the canvas and draw content

```
ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, origin.x, origin.y);
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

To use if you have the mouse coordinates

```
const zoomBy = 1.1;                    // zoom in amount
scaleAt(mouse.x, mouse.y, zoomBy);     // will zoom in at mouse x, y
scaleAt(mouse.x, mouse.y, 1 / zoomBy); // will zoom out by same amount at mouse x,y
```

To restore the default transform

```
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
```

### The inversions

To get the coordinates of a point in the zoomed coordinate system and the screen position of a point in the zoomed coordinate system

**Screen to world**

```
function toWorld(x, y) {  // convert to world coordinates
    x = (x - origin.x) / scale;
    y = (y - origin.y) / scale;
    return {x, y};
}
```

**World to screen**

```
function toScreen(x, y) {
    x = x * scale + origin.x;
    y = y * scale + origin.y;
    return {x, y};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the solution from @Phrogz (which is awesome in itself btw) to include the following features:

1. Allow a range of zoom levels (not infinite)
2. Default or start with the most zoomed out level
3. Allow for layers of canvas objects (zoom all canvas objects in an array simultaneously)
4. Zooming out does not show area outside original view.

Hope this helps someone.

```
    let layer = [];
    layer[0] = document.getElementById("canvas-layer-001");
    layer[1] = document.getElementById("canvas-layer-002");
    layer[2] = document.getElementById("canvas-layer-top");

    let context = [];
    context[0] = layer[0].getContext("2d");
    context[1] = layer[1].getContext("2d");
    context[2] = layer[2].getContext("2d");

    const MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL = 0;
    const MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL = 20;

    let scaleFactor = 1.1;
    let zoomLevel = 0;

    let zoom = function(clicks) {
        if( zoomLevel + clicks < MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL ||
            zoomLevel + clicks > MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL ) { return; }

        let factor = Math.pow(scaleFactor,clicks);

        for( let i = 0 ; i < context.length ; ++i ) {
            let pt = context[i].transformedPoint(lastX,lastY);

            context[i].translate( pt.x, pt.y );
            context[i].scale( factor, factor );
            context[i].translate( -pt.x, -pt.y );

            let adjust = false;
            pt = context[i].transformedPoint( 0, 0 );
            if( pt.x < 0 ) { adjust = true; }
            if( pt.y < 0 ) { adjust = true; }

            if( adjust ) {
                context[i].translate( pt.x, pt.y );
                adjust = false;
            }

            pt = context[i].transformedPoint( layer[i].width, layer[i].height );
            if( pt.x > layer[i].width ) { adjust = true; }
            if( pt.y > layer[i].height ) { adjust = true; }

            if( adjust ) {
                context[i].translate( pt.x - layer[i].width, pt.y - layer[i].height );
                adjust = false;
            }
        }

        zoomLevel += clicks;
        draw();
    }
```