# Edge Correction on HTML5 canvas point based zoom and Pan

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I have implemented a point based zooming functionality using the stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189968/zoom-canvas-to-mouse-cursor).

I can't fit the image inside the view area. It pans indefinitely. How can I fit this image inside the view port while pan the image?

Comment: Are you saying you want a button that fits the image, or that you want to stop zooming once it's all the way zoomed out?

Comment: I am saying that it doesn't fit into the view port while panning indefinitely. How can fix this issue?