# Zooming via HTML5 Canvas Context and drawing a grid over a given image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Using the HTML5  element, I would like to load an image file (PNG, JPEG, etc.), draw it to the canvas, and then draw a grid on top of the image;

also, I am trying to set a rectangle margin and a fully transparent content for the rectangle;

the example that I am trying to modify can be found [here](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_zoom_to_cursor.html)

and on my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VMvqt/8/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0048)http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_zoom_to_cursor.html -->
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <title>Zooming via HTML5 Canvas Context</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body { background:#eee; margin:1em; text-align:center; }
        canvas { display:block; margin:1em auto; background:#fff; border:1px solid #ccc }
    </style>
</head><body style="-webkit-user-select: none;">
<p>Showing how to use transform methods on the HTML5 Canvas Context to selectively zoom in and out. Drag to pan. Click to zoom at that location. Shift-click to zoom out. Mousewheel up/down over the canvas to zoom in to/out from that location.</p>
<p>By redrawing the canvas at different scales the strokes remain smooth during zooming. For example, zoom in on the earring or circle on the forehead to see fine detail.</p>
<canvas width="800" height="600"></canvas>
<p id="footer">Copyright © 2011 <a href="mailto:!@phrogz.net">Gavin Kistner</a>. Written to support <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189968/zoom-to-cursor-calculations/5526721#5526721">this Stack Overflow answer</a>.</p>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
    canvas.width = 800; canvas.height = 600;
    var gkhead = new Image;
    var ball   = new Image;
    window.onload = function(){     
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        trackTransforms(ctx);
        function redraw(){
            // Clear the entire canvas
            var p1 = ctx.transformedPoint(0,0);
            var p2 = ctx.transformedPoint(canvas.width,canvas.height);
            ctx.clearRect(p1.x,p1.y,p2.x-p1.x,p2.y-p1.y);

            // Alternatively:
            // ctx.save();
            // ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
            // ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
            // ctx.restore();

            ctx.drawImage(gkhead,50,50);//punct stanga sus imagine cu marton
            console.log(ctx);

            ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
            ctx.fillRect(50,50,60,60);

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineWidth = 10;//rama 10
            ctx.moveTo(399,250);
            ctx.lineTo(474,256);
            ctx.stroke();

            ctx.save();
            ctx.translate(4,2);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineWidth = 1;//rama 1
            ctx.moveTo(436,253);
            ctx.lineTo(437.5,233);
            ctx.stroke();

            ctx.save();
            ctx.translate(438.5,223);
            ctx.strokeStyle = '#06c';
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineWidth = 0.05;
            for (var i=0;i<60;++i){
                ctx.rotate(6*i*Math.PI/180);
                ctx.moveTo(9,0);
                ctx.lineTo(10,0);
                ctx.rotate(-6*i*Math.PI/180);
            }
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.restore();

            //ctx.beginPath();
            //ctx.lineWidth = 0.2;
            //ctx.arc(438.5,223,10,0,Math.PI*2);
            //ctx.stroke();
            //ctx.restore();

            //ctx.drawImage(ball,379,233,40,40);//bila stanga
            //ctx.drawImage(ball,454,239,40,40);//bila dreapta
            //ctx.drawImage(ball,310,295,20,20);//bila jos
            //ctx.drawImage(ball,314.5,296.5,5,5);//ochi stang
            //ctx.drawImage(ball,319,297.2,5,5);//ochi drept
        }
        redraw();

        var lastX=canvas.width/2, lastY=canvas.height/2;
        var dragStart,dragged;
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',function(evt){
            document.body.style.mozUserSelect = document.body.style.webkitUserSelect = document.body.style.userSelect = 'none';
            lastX = evt.offsetX || (evt.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft);
            lastY = evt.offsetY || (evt.pageY - canvas.offsetTop);
            console.log(lastX + ' ' + lastY);
            dragStart = ctx.transformedPoint(lastX,lastY);
            dragged = false;
        },false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',function(evt){
            lastX = evt.offsetX || (evt.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft);
            lastY = evt.offsetY || (evt.pageY - canvas.offsetTop);
            dragged = true;
            if (dragStart){
                var pt = ctx.transformedPoint(lastX,lastY);
                ctx.translate(pt.x-dragStart.x,pt.y-dragStart.y);
                redraw();
            }
        },false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',function(evt){
            dragStart = null;
            if (!dragged) zoom(evt.shiftKey ? -1 : 1 );
        },false);

        var scaleFactor = 1.1;
        var zoom = function(clicks){
            var pt = ctx.transformedPoint(lastX,lastY);
            ctx.translate(pt.x,pt.y);
            var factor = Math.pow(scaleFactor,clicks);
            ctx.scale(factor,factor);
            ctx.translate(-pt.x,-pt.y);
            redraw();
        }

        var handleScroll = function(evt){
            var delta = evt.wheelDelta ? evt.wheelDelta/40 : evt.detail ? -evt.detail : 0;
            if (delta) zoom(delta);
            return evt.preventDefault() && false;
        };
        canvas.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll',handleScroll,false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mousewheel',handleScroll,false);
    };
    gkhead.src = 'marton.jpg';
    //console.log(gkhead);//img src
    ball.src   = 'http://phrogz.net/tmp/alphaball.png';
    //console.log(ball);

    // Adds ctx.getTransform() - returns an SVGMatrix
    // Adds ctx.transformedPoint(x,y) - returns an SVGPoint
    function trackTransforms(ctx){
        var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",'svg');
        var xform = svg.createSVGMatrix();
        ctx.getTransform = function(){ return xform; };

        var savedTransforms = [];
        var save = ctx.save;
        ctx.save = function(){
            savedTransforms.push(xform.translate(0,0));
            return save.call(ctx);
        };
        var restore = ctx.restore;
        ctx.restore = function(){
            xform = savedTransforms.pop();
            return restore.call(ctx);
        };

        var scale = ctx.scale;
        ctx.scale = function(sx,sy){
            xform = xform.scaleNonUniform(sx,sy);
            return scale.call(ctx,sx,sy);
        };
        var rotate = ctx.rotate;
        ctx.rotate = function(radians){
            xform = xform.rotate(radians*180/Math.PI);
            return rotate.call(ctx,radians);
        };
        var translate = ctx.translate;
        ctx.translate = function(dx,dy){
            xform = xform.translate(dx,dy);
            return translate.call(ctx,dx,dy);
        };
        var transform = ctx.transform;
        ctx.transform = function(a,b,c,d,e,f){
            var m2 = svg.createSVGMatrix();
            m2.a=a; m2.b=b; m2.c=c; m2.d=d; m2.e=e; m2.f=f;
            xform = xform.multiply(m2);
            return transform.call(ctx,a,b,c,d,e,f);
        };
        var setTransform = ctx.setTransform;
        ctx.setTransform = function(a,b,c,d,e,f){
            xform.a = a;
            xform.b = b;
            xform.c = c;
            xform.d = d;
            xform.e = e;
            xform.f = f;
            return setTransform.call(ctx,a,b,c,d,e,f);
        };
        var pt  = svg.createSVGPoint();
        ctx.transformedPoint = function(x,y){
            pt.x=x; pt.y=y;
            return pt.matrixTransform(xform.inverse());
        }
    }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you post a fiddle of what you've done so far ? And tell what is the issue that is stopping you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so, i managed to write the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0048)http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_zoom_to_cursor.html -->
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Zooming via HTML5 Canvas Context</title>
</head><body style="-webkit-user-select: none;">

<canvas width="800" height="600"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
    canvas.width = 800; canvas.height = 600;
    var gkhead = new Image;
    var ball   = new Image;

    var square_size = 10;

    window.onload = function(){
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        trackTransforms(ctx);
        function redraw(){
            // Clear the entire canvas
            var p1 = ctx.transformedPoint(0,0);
            var p2 = ctx.transformedPoint(canvas.width,canvas.height);
            ctx.clearRect(p1.x,p1.y,p2.x-p1.x,p2.y-p1.y);

            ctx.drawImage(gkhead,50,50);//punct stanga sus imagine cu marton
    //console.log(ctx);
            color='ff0000';
    w = gkhead.width;
    //console.log(w);
    h = gkhead.height;
    //console.log(h);
            var i = 0;
            i = i + 1;
            if(i==1)color='ff0000';
            if(i==2)color='00ff00';
            if(i==3){
    color='0000ff';
    i=0;
    }

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(50,50,gkhead.width,gkhead.height);
            ctx.lineWidth = 1;
            ctx.strokeStyle = "#" + color;
            ctx.stroke();

            var ind = 0;
            for(var j = 0; j < gkhead.width - square_size; j = j + square_size){
                ind++;
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.lineWidth = 1;
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                ctx.moveTo(50 + ( ind * square_size ), 50);
                ctx.lineTo(50 + ( ind * square_size ), 50 + gkhead.height);
                ctx.stroke();
            }

            var ind = 0;
            for(var j = 0; j < gkhead.height - square_size; j = j + square_size){
                ind++;
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.lineWidth = 1;
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                ctx.moveTo(50, 50 + ( ind * square_size ));
                ctx.lineTo(50 + gkhead.width,50 + ( ind * square_size ));
                ctx.stroke();
            }

            ctx.save();
            ctx.translate(438.5,223);
            ctx.strokeStyle = '#06c';
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineWidth = 0.05;

            for (var i=0;i<60;++i){
                ctx.rotate(6*i*Math.PI/180);
                ctx.moveTo(9,0);
                ctx.lineTo(10,0);
                ctx.rotate(-6*i*Math.PI/180);
            }
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.restore();
        }
        redraw();

        var lastX=canvas.width/2, lastY=canvas.height/2;
        var dragStart,dragged;

        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',function(evt){
            document.body.style.mozUserSelect = document.body.style.webkitUserSelect = document.body.style.userSelect = 'none';
            lastX = evt.offsetX || (evt.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft);
            lastY = evt.offsetY || (evt.pageY - canvas.offsetTop);
            console.log(lastX + ' ' + lastY);
            dragStart = ctx.transformedPoint(lastX,lastY);
            dragged = false;
        },false);

        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',function(evt){
            lastX = evt.offsetX || (evt.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft);
            lastY = evt.offsetY || (evt.pageY - canvas.offsetTop);
            dragged = true;
            if (dragStart){
                var pt = ctx.transformedPoint(lastX,lastY);
                ctx.translate(pt.x-dragStart.x,pt.y-dragStart.y);
                redraw();
            }
        },false);

        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',function(evt){
            dragStart = null;
            if (!dragged) zoom(evt.shiftKey ? -1 : 1 );
        },false);

        var scaleFactor = 1.1;
        var zoom = function(clicks){
            var pt = ctx.transformedPoint(lastX,lastY);
            ctx.translate(pt.x,pt.y);
            var factor = Math.pow(scaleFactor,clicks);
            ctx.scale(factor,factor);
            ctx.translate(-pt.x,-pt.y);
            redraw();
        }

        var handleScroll = function(evt){
            var delta = evt.wheelDelta ? evt.wheelDelta/40 : evt.detail ? -evt.detail : 0;
            if (delta) zoom(delta);
            return evt.preventDefault() && false;
        };
        canvas.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll',handleScroll,false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mousewheel',handleScroll,false);
    };
    gkhead.src = 'http://www.william.ro/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/13.jpg';
    //console.log(gkhead.width);
    //console.log(gkhead);//img src
    ball.src   = 'http://phrogz.net/tmp/alphaball.png';
    //console.log(ball);

    // Adds ctx.getTransform() - returns an SVGMatrix
    // Adds ctx.transformedPoint(x,y) - returns an SVGPoint
    function trackTransforms(ctx){
        var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",'svg');
        var xform = svg.createSVGMatrix();
        ctx.getTransform = function(){ return xform; };

        var savedTransforms = [];
        var save = ctx.save;
        ctx.save = function(){
            savedTransforms.push(xform.translate(0,0));
            return save.call(ctx);
        };
        var restore = ctx.restore;
        ctx.restore = function(){
            xform = savedTransforms.pop();
            return restore.call(ctx);
        };

        var scale = ctx.scale;
        ctx.scale = function(sx,sy){
            xform = xform.scaleNonUniform(sx,sy);
            return scale.call(ctx,sx,sy);
        };
        var rotate = ctx.rotate;
        ctx.rotate = function(radians){
            xform = xform.rotate(radians*180/Math.PI);
            return rotate.call(ctx,radians);
        };
        var translate = ctx.translate;
        ctx.translate = function(dx,dy){
            xform = xform.translate(dx,dy);
            return translate.call(ctx,dx,dy);
        };
        var transform = ctx.transform;
        ctx.transform = function(a,b,c,d,e,f){
            var m2 = svg.createSVGMatrix();
            m2.a=a; m2.b=b; m2.c=c; m2.d=d; m2.e=e; m2.f=f;
            xform = xform.multiply(m2);
            return transform.call(ctx,a,b,c,d,e,f);
        };
        var setTransform = ctx.setTransform;
        ctx.setTransform = function(a,b,c,d,e,f){
            xform.a = a;
            xform.b = b;
            xform.c = c;
            xform.d = d;
            xform.e = e;
            xform.f = f;
            return setTransform.call(ctx,a,b,c,d,e,f);
        };
        var pt  = svg.createSVGPoint();
        ctx.transformedPoint = function(x,y){
            pt.x=x; pt.y=y;
            return pt.matrixTransform(xform.inverse());
        }
    }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```