# Getting relative mouse position on canvas after scaling

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

**Problem:** I'm working with an HTML canvas.  My canvas has a background image that multiple people can draw over in real-time (via socket.io), but drawing breaks if you've zoomed in.

**Cause:** To calculate where to start and end a line, I normalize input upon capture to be between 0 and 1 inclusive, like so:

```
// Pseudocode
line.x = mousePosition.x / canvas.width;    
line.y = mousePosition.y / canvas.height;
```

Because of this, the `canvas` can be of any size and in any position.

To implement a zoom-on-scroll functionality, I simply `translate` based on the current mouse position, `scale` the canvas by a factor of 2, then `translate` back the negative value of the current mouse position (as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5526721/5665799)).

**Here's where the problem lies**

When I zoom, the canvas doesn't seem to have a notion of it's original size.

For instance, let's say I have a 1000px square canvas.  Using my normalized `x` and `y` above, the upper left corner is `0, 0` and the lower right is `1, 1`.

I then zoom into the center through scaling by a factor of 2.  I would expect that my new upper left would be `0.5, 0.5` and my lower right would be `0.75, 0.75`, but it isn't.  Even when I zoom in, the upper left is still `0, 0` and the lower right is `1, 1`.

The result is that when I zoom in and draw, the lines appear where they would as if I were not zoomed at all.  If I zoomed into the center and "drew" in the upper left, I'd see nothing until I scrolled out to see that the line was actually getting drawn on the original upper left.

**What I need to know:** When zoomed, is there a way to get a read on what your new origin is relative to the un-zoomed canvas, or what amount of the canvas is hidden? Either of these would let me zoom in and draw and have it track correctly.

---

If I'm totally off base here and there's a better way to approach this, I'm all ears.  If you need additional information, I'll provide what I can.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear to me what you mean by "zoomed".

Zoomed =

- made the canvas a different size?
- changed the transform on the canvas
- used CSS transform?
- used CSS zoom?

I'm going to assume it's `transform` on the canvas in which case it's something like

```
function getElementRelativeMousePosition(e) {
  return [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];
}

function getCanvasRelativeMousePosition(e) {
  const pos = getElementRelativeMousePosition(e);
  pos[0] = pos[0] * ctx.canvas.width / ctx.canvas.clientWidth;
  pos[1] = pos[1] * ctx.canvas.height / ctx.canvas.clientHeight;
  return pos;
}

function getComputedMousePosition(e) {
  const pos = getCanvasRelativeMousePosition(e);
  const p = new DOMPoint(...pos);
  const point = inverseOriginTransform.transformPoint(p);
  return [point.x, point.y];
}
```

Where `inverseOriginTransform` is the inverse of whatever transform you're using to zoom and scroll the contents of the canvas.

```js
const settings = {
  zoom: 1,
  xoffset: 0,
  yoffset: 0,
};

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const lines = [
   [[100, 10], [200, 30]],
   [[50, 50], [100, 30]],
];
let newStart;
let newEnd;
let originTransform = new DOMMatrix();
let inverseOriginTransform = new DOMMatrix();

function setZoomAndOffsetTransform() {
  originTransform = new DOMMatrix();
  originTransform.translateSelf(settings.xoffset, settings.yoffset);
  originTransform.scaleSelf(settings.zoom, settings.zoom);
  inverseOriginTransform = originTransform.inverse();
} 

const ui = document.querySelector('#ui')
addSlider(settings, 'zoom', ui, 0.25, 3, draw);
addSlider(settings, 'xoffset', ui, -100, +100, draw);
addSlider(settings, 'yoffset', ui, -100, +100, draw);

draw();

function updateAndDraw() {
  draw();
}

function getElementRelativeMousePosition(e) {
  return [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];
}

function getCanvasRelativeMousePosition(e) {
  const pos = getElementRelativeMousePosition(e);
  pos[0] = pos[0] * ctx.canvas.width / ctx.canvas.clientWidth;
  pos[1] = pos[1] * ctx.canvas.height / ctx.canvas.clientHeight;
  return pos;
}

function getTransformRelativeMousePosition(e) {
  const pos = getCanvasRelativeMousePosition(e);
  const p = new DOMPoint(...pos);
  const point = inverseOriginTransform.transformPoint(p);
  return [point.x, point.y];
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  const pos = getTransformRelativeMousePosition(e);
  if (newStart) {
  } else {
    newStart = pos;
    newEnd = pos;
  }
});

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (newStart) {
    newEnd = getTransformRelativeMousePosition(e);
    draw();
  }
});

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
  if (newStart) {
    lines.push([newStart, newEnd]);
    newStart = undefined;
  }
});


function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  ctx.save();
  setZoomAndOffsetTransform();
  ctx.setTransform(
      originTransform.a,
      originTransform.b,
      originTransform.c,
      originTransform.d,
      originTransform.e,
      originTransform.f);
  ctx.beginPath();
  for (const line of lines) {
    ctx.moveTo(...line[0]);
    ctx.lineTo(...line[1]);
  }
  if (newStart) {
     ctx.moveTo(...newStart);
     ctx.lineTo(...newEnd);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
}

function addSlider(obj, prop, parent, min, max, callback) {
  const valueRange = max - min;
  const sliderRange = 100;
  
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.class = 'range';
  
  const input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = 'range';
  input.min = 0;
  input.max = sliderRange;
 
  const label = document.createElement('span');
  label.textContent = `${prop}: `;
  
  const valueElem = document.createElement('span');
  
  function setInputValue(v) {
    input.value = (v - min) * sliderRange / valueRange;
  }
  
  input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    const v = parseFloat(input.value) * valueRange / sliderRange + min;
    valueElem.textContent = v.toFixed(1);
    obj[prop] = v;
    callback();
  });
  
  const v = obj[prop];
  valueElem.textContent = v.toFixed(1);
  setInputValue(v);
  
  div.appendChild(input);
  div.appendChild(label);
  div.appendChild(valueElem);
  parent.appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
#app { display: flex; }
```

```html
<div id="app"><canvas></canvas><div id="ui"></div>
```

Note: I didn't bother making zoom always zoom from the center. To do so would require adjusting xoffset and yoffset as the zoom changes.

Answer (score 1):

Use HTMLElement.prototype.getBoundingClientRect() to get displayed size and position of canvas in DOM. From the displayed size and origin size, calculates the scale of the canvas.

Example:

```
canvas.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var b = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var scale = canvas.width / parseFloat(b.width);
    var x = (event.clientX - b.left) * scale;
    var y = (event.clientY - b.top) * scale;
    // Marks mouse position
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
});
```

Comment: `scale` is always `1` in this scenario.  I'm essentially dividing `canvas.width` by `canvas.width`