# Zoom into point in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to zoom into a given point and i honestly cannot understand what i am doing wrong.

First i get the mouse point and use the canvas transform matrix to get the point in canvas context (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-context-2d-gettransform).

```
const domPoint = new window.DOMPoint(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
const currMatrix = this.canvasManager.ctx.getTransform();
const canvasPoint = domPoint.matrixTransform(currMatrix);
```

Then i translate, scale and translate back using the  matrix returned in getTransform (DOMMatrix object).

```
const m = currMatrix
.translateSelf(canvasPoint.x, canvasPoint.y)
.scaleSelf(scale, scale)
.translateSelf(-canvasPoint.x, -canvasPoint.y);
```

Finally i set the transform using the last matrix.

```
this.ctx.setTransform(this.zoom.matrix)
```

The method i am using is based on one [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189968/zoom-canvas-to-mouse-cursor/5526721#5526721).

Here's my code

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var currMatrix = ctx.getTransform();

var plusBtn = document.getElementById("plus");
var minusBtn = document.getElementById("minus");
var infoP = document.getElementById("info");

var zoom;
var scale = 1;
const scaleFactor = 0.1;

function draw() {
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 ctx.setTransform(currMatrix)
 ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
 ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
}
draw()

function getDomPoint(event) {
 const offSetCanvasLeft = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  const offSetCanvasTop = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;

 return {
    x: event.pageX - offSetCanvasLeft,
    y: event.pageY - offSetCanvasTop,
  }
}

function domToCanvasPoint(point) {
 const domPoint = new window.DOMPoint(point.x, point.y);
 return domPoint.matrixTransform(currMatrix);
}

function updateScale() {
  scale = zoom === 'in' ? scale + scaleFactor : scale - scaleFactor ;
  setDebugInfo(scale)
}

function zoomMatrixIntoPoint(point) {
 currMatrix = currMatrix
    .translateSelf(point.x, point.y)
    .scaleSelf(scale, scale)
    .translateSelf(-point.x, -point.y);
}

function setDebugInfo(msg) {
 infoP.innerHTML = msg;
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {  
 const domPoint = getDomPoint(event);
  const canvasPoint = domToCanvasPoint(domPoint);
  updateScale();
  zoomMatrixIntoPoint(canvasPoint);
  draw()
}, false);

plusBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {    
 zoom = 'in'
  setDebugInfo(`ZOOM IN with scale ${scale}`)
}, false);

minusBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {    
 zoom = 'out'
  setDebugInfo(`ZOOM OUT with scale ${scale}`)
}, false);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
<button id="plus">+</button>
<button id="minus">-</button>
<p id="info">info here!</p>
```

Would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Given that `getTransform()` and `translateSelf` etc. are not Canvas2D API functions, you are clearly omitting details that are essential for understand the complete picture.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer. In fact getTransform is. It returns the current transformation matrix in a DOMMatrix object. translateSelf is just on method of DOMMatrix object.

But if you can help me using SVG matrix no problem for me.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i just added some info that might help.

Comment: Usually you translate by -x/-y, then scale, then translate back, so what happens if you just swap the `-` signs before/after?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans never seen that approach but no. Devastating effect.

Comment: @Kaiido You are right sorry. Codes are on different files. Updated

Comment: @Kaiido what about the algorithm. Wont it supposed to be right?

Comment: You can find one example here on the following link. https://jsfiddle.net/diogoaleixo/cx5vq0uz/12/

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is a simple logical error.

You are keeping `curMatrix` and update it every time.
This means that all the values you do pass to `translateSelf` and `scaleSelf` are relative to the previous values.

However, when you do `scale -= scaleFactor` or `scale += scaleFactor`, `scale` is the **absolute** scale value.
So when you use it later in `scaleSelf`, you are quickly setting an huge absolute scale value, which won't get down until it becomes less than `1`.

```
(1.1 * 1.2 * 1.3 * 1.4 * 1.5 * 1.6) => real scale is 5.8
```

and

```
(1.1 * 1.2 * 1.3 * 1.2 * 1.1 * 1) => real scale is 2.3
                 ^-- click zoom-out
```

So all you need to fix is the line which sets this `scale` value: Instead of incrementing this value, set it always `1` based.

```
scale = zoom === 'in' ? 1 + scaleFactor : 1 - scaleFactor ;
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var currMatrix = ctx.getTransform();

var plusBtn = document.getElementById("plus");
var minusBtn = document.getElementById("minus");
var infoP = document.getElementById("info");

var zoom;
var scale = 1;
const scaleFactor = 0.1;

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.setTransform(currMatrix)
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
}
draw()

function getDomPoint(event) {
  const offSetCanvasLeft = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  const offSetCanvasTop = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;

  return {
    x: event.pageX - offSetCanvasLeft,
    y: event.pageY - offSetCanvasTop,
  }
}

function domToCanvasPoint(point) {
  const domPoint = new window.DOMPoint(point.x, point.y);
  return domPoint.matrixTransform(currMatrix);
}

function updateScale() {
  scale = zoom === 'in' ? 1 + scaleFactor : 1 - scaleFactor;
  setDebugInfo(scale)
}

function zoomMatrixIntoPoint(point) {
  currMatrix
    .translateSelf(point.x, point.y)
    .scaleSelf(scale, scale)
    .translateSelf(-point.x, -point.y);
}

function setDebugInfo(msg) {
  infoP.innerHTML = msg;
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  const domPoint = getDomPoint(event);
  const canvasPoint = domToCanvasPoint(domPoint);
  updateScale();
  zoomMatrixIntoPoint(canvasPoint);
  draw()
}, false);

plusBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  zoom = 'in'
  setDebugInfo(`ZOOM IN with scale ${scale}`)
}, false);

minusBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  zoom = 'out'
  setDebugInfo(`ZOOM OUT with scale ${scale}`)
}, false);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
<button id="plus">+</button>
<button id="minus">-</button>
<p id="info">info here!</p>
```

Also note that *[DOMMatrix#scale()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix)* accepts optional *origin* arguments, which would allow you to avoid the two transform calls:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var currMatrix = ctx.getTransform();

var plusBtn = document.getElementById("plus");
var minusBtn = document.getElementById("minus");
var infoP = document.getElementById("info");

var zoom;
var scale = 1;
const scaleFactor = 0.1;

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.setTransform(currMatrix)
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
}
draw()

function getDomPoint(event) {
  const offSetCanvasLeft = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  const offSetCanvasTop = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;

  return {
    x: event.pageX - offSetCanvasLeft,
    y: event.pageY - offSetCanvasTop,
  }
}

function domToCanvasPoint(point) {
  const domPoint = new window.DOMPoint(point.x, point.y);
  return domPoint.matrixTransform(currMatrix);
}

function updateScale() {
  scale = zoom === 'in' ? 1 + scaleFactor : 1 - scaleFactor;
  setDebugInfo(scale)
}

function zoomMatrixIntoPoint(point) {
  currMatrix
  // scaleSelf(scaleX, scaleY, scaleZ, originX, originY, originZ)  
    .scaleSelf(scale, scale, 1, point.x, point.y, 0)
}

function setDebugInfo(msg) {
  infoP.innerHTML = msg;
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  const domPoint = getDomPoint(event);
  const canvasPoint = domToCanvasPoint(domPoint);
  updateScale();
  zoomMatrixIntoPoint(canvasPoint);
  draw()
}, false);

plusBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  zoom = 'in'
  setDebugInfo(`ZOOM IN with scale ${scale}`)
}, false);

minusBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  zoom = 'out'
  setDebugInfo(`ZOOM OUT with scale ${scale}`)
}, false);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
<button id="plus">+</button>
<button id="minus">-</button>
<p id="info">info here!</p>
```

And if you need all your values to be absolute (i.e translate too), then simply create a new DOMMatrix every time, and here keep your original scale increment:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var currMatrix = ctx.getTransform();

var plusBtn = document.getElementById("plus");
var minusBtn = document.getElementById("minus");
var infoP = document.getElementById("info");

var zoom;
var scale = 1;
const scaleFactor = 0.1;

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.setTransform(currMatrix)
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
}
draw()

function getDomPoint(event) {
  const offSetCanvasLeft = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  const offSetCanvasTop = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;

  return {
    x: event.pageX - offSetCanvasLeft,
    y: event.pageY - offSetCanvasTop,
  }
}

function domToCanvasPoint(point) {
  const domPoint = new window.DOMPoint(point.x, point.y);
  return domPoint.matrixTransform(currMatrix);
}

function updateScale() {
  scale = zoom === 'in' ? scale + scaleFactor : scale - scaleFactor;
  setDebugInfo(scale)
}

function zoomMatrixIntoPoint(point) {
  // create a new DOMMatrix
  currMatrix = new DOMMatrix()
    .scaleSelf(scale, scale, 1, point.x, point.y, 0)
}

function setDebugInfo(msg) {
  infoP.innerHTML = msg;
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  const domPoint = getDomPoint(event);
  const canvasPoint = domToCanvasPoint(domPoint);
  updateScale();
  zoomMatrixIntoPoint(canvasPoint);
  draw()
}, false);

plusBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  zoom = 'in'
  setDebugInfo(`ZOOM IN with scale ${scale}`)
}, false);

minusBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  zoom = 'out'
  setDebugInfo(`ZOOM OUT with scale ${scale}`)
}, false);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
<button id="plus">+</button>
<button id="minus">-</button>
<p id="info">info here!</p>
```

Comment: You are right. That was an error. But it is not the error.

I have updated the fiddle to use SVG matrix. Using SVG matrix everything runs fine. Using DOMMatrix, i run into unexpected behaviour. https://jsfiddle.net/diogoaleixo/8rsyv4oL/55/

Comment: Because then you are creating a new SVGMatrix every time, and you do set its values to **absolute** values.

Comment: Sorry i am not getting it. Yes i am creating one SVGMatrix every time. But assigning the a,b,c,d,e and f values to it from the currMatrix variable. Anyway, the code you posted does not appear to do the right thing.

Comment: And what is the right thing? How is this not the right thing? And It is absolute because `curMatrix` never gets updated there. So it is always  `1 0 0 1 0 0` and your svg matrix initialisation step is a noop, you're just setting the same values, until you call xxxSelf, which are then absolute values. My code only fixed scale, maybe you want `translate` to be set absolutely every time?

Comment: You seem like someone who know this. What is the best solutions ? If you go to the last fiddle i posted, you can see the correct behaviour using the SVGMatrix.

Comment: I just saw that your last example does not work ok. If i zoom inside the element, the zoom is moving on the wrong way. And if i come go zoom 100,90,80,70,40,25, and then all the way arrow the currMatrix.a value will not be 1 like it would suppose to be. Do you know what is wrong?