# Zoom canvas with translate and matrix tranform in angular prolem

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas

After seeing this example
[Zoom Canvas to Mouse Cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189968/zoom-canvas-to-mouse-cursor/5526721#5526721)

http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_zoom_to_cursor.html

I followed the example to port it to angular but fail. I have been observing the svg matrix.
this.svgMatrix = this.svg.createSVGMatrix(), It doesnt get changed in value. But what i see from the example above, it did change in value of the svg matrix when performing move action to the picture. Below is the link to example code i have written.

Please enlighten me which part i am missing.

```
DEMO
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Wd2aHNtgacuIcsUp?open=lib%2Fapp.ts